# Align right in table if no expression

Tags: tables, pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I am using `pgfplotstabletypset` to read in a table -- I want all cells in the first column with the expression `Factor` in them to be aligned to the left and bolded, and I want all cells without that expression to be aligned to the left and not bolded.  Not sure how to implement these rules.

Comment: So you dont want the entire column to be bolded?

Comment: Right, I want a cell to be bolded and aligned left in the first column if it has the word 'Factor' in it.  Otherwise, I want it to be non-bold and left aligned.

Comment: See my answer for a possible solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you have your data file in .csv format created when compiling the following:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{filecontents*}{scientists.csv}
name,surname,age
Albert,Einstein,133
Factor and,Curie,145 % add the word and just to illustrate
Thomas,Edison,165
\end{filecontents*}
```

Once the `scientists.csv` has been created then you can compile the following which will do what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[%
    col sep=comma,%
    string type,%
    columns/name/.style={column name=Name, column type={|l}, string replace*={Factor}{\bfseries Factor}},
    columns/surname/.style={column name=Surname, column type={|l}},%
    columns/age/.style={column name=Age, column type={|c|}},%
    every head row/.style={before row=\hline,after row=\hline},%
    every last row/.style={after row=\hline},%
    ]{scientists.csv}
\end{document}
```

The tricky part is to use `string replace*={Factor}{\bfseries Factor}`. Thus we get:

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much -- most of what I need -- is it possible to have the alignment be different if the word 'Factor' appears?  Is it possible to have an if/else statement for the column type = ??  Thanks,